# Twitter embed support for Android 4.2 browser

Tags: javascript, twitter, android-4.2-jelly-bean

We're using Twitter's embed code on our site that is displayed on a hardware kiosk running Android 4.2. It appears that Twitter has recently stopped supporting Android 4.2's browser.

I verified it by going to Twitters documentation site for embedding (https://dev.twitter.com/web/embedded-tweets) on a 4.2 emulator. Where it says "National Park Tweets", it should actually be displaying the tweets.

Any suggestions on how to get this working?

[image: Twitter Embed documentation screenshot]